# Java Thread.suspend() gracefully

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

EDIT: Updated question to explain exactly what I need.

So I am attaching a javaagent to a process using

```
VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(processPid);
vm.loadAgent(jarPath);
```

Now my agent runs on a separate thread. Now what I need to do is load all my transformers before any classes load. There is a thread in the attached process that loads all the classes. I want to be able to suspend this thread at the right time (without causing deadlocks) to wait for all my initialization (including a download) AND THEN register my transformers. It is important that the transformers are registred before anything else than the main class loads so I can modify the classes however I want.

I am currently just getting the thread by it's name and calling `suspend()` on it. But that causes deadlocks. Is there any way for me to make that thread wait on me?

Things I've tried:

1. Transforming the main class instantly to add a `Thread.sleep()`, didn't work because my agent loads after the main class
2. Using `Thread.suspend` which causes deadlocks.

Comment: If you're going to ask a question that you seem to know is either very tricky or impossible, why not give us ALL the information - describe completely what you're trying to accomplush and why you need to do what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

What does "a thread that I do not have control over" mean?  If your code calls `t.suspend()`, then that *is* a kind of control.  Are you trying to tell us that the thread executes *code* for which you can not obtain the source?

---

What does "gracefully suspend" mean?  If your program called `t.suspend()`, would it be possible for your program to decide whether it had suspended the thread at a "good" time?

You say that you want to suspend the thread while your program does something else.  Can you explain in more detail what the thread does, and what you want your program to do while the thread is suspended, and why you can't allow both things to happen at the same time?

If your program could tell the difference between a good time and a bad time, and it picked a bad time, then would it make sense for the program to resume the thread and then try again later?

Comment: Alright I updated my question. And yes I can wait and determine when I can call suspend on it. Since it only causes deadlocks every now and then I am sure that there is some way of determining that moment when I cab suspend the thread.

Comment: So, based on your update, it sounds like it's not a periodic task, but something you want to do just one time, and it sounds like the window of opportunity is very narrow.  IMO, you are going to have to find a different way to solve your problem.